# .htaccess not working - on add on domain

Tags: .htaccess

The original domain files are under `/home/account/public_html`, the add-on domain is `/home/account/add-on-domain`.

Both sites have a `.htaccess` file, all the same, apart from the domain names, both are in main directory.

Main domain:

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch -FollowSymLinks -Indexes

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain1.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

add on domain:

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch -FollowSymLinks -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain2.co.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain2.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]
```

There is more in the `.htaccess`, the add-on doesn't read it at all.

adding `Allowoverrides All` on main domain crashes it, does nothing on add on domain.

Comment: You mentioned cPanel in your [earlier question](https://serverfault.com/questions/1061765/htaccess-file-in-addon-domain-not-working) (that was closed), which potentially makes this question off-topic. However, do you have access to the server config? `AllowOverride All` (note, there is no `s`) needs to be added to the appropriate `<Directory>` block in the server config. But if you are using cPanel then it should have already have done this for you?

Comment: Again, you seem to have logged in as a different user, which is why you can't "comment" or "edit your question". (?)

Comment: Yes, I was logged in with a different account don't know what happened :/

Comment: To clarify, the addon domain `.htaccess` file is located at `/home/account/add-on-domain/.htaccess`? Do you have any other `.htaccess` files along the filesystem path? Do you have any other directives in this `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch -FollowSymLinks -Indexes
> ```

Try setting `FollowSymLinks` instead of `SymLinksIfOwnerMatch` for the AddOn domain. For example:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> adding `Allowoverrides All` on main domain crashes it, does nothing on add on domain.

This would seem to imply that `.htaccess` overrides are not enabled for the addon domain, or rather, they are not enabled for the filesystem path that the addon domain points to. Unfortunately, this requires access to the server config to resolve - which you don't appear to have access to.

You would need to add `AllowOverride All` to the `<VirtualHost>` container for the addon domain to cover the directory that the addon domain points to. For example:

```
<Directory /home/account/add-on-domain>
    # Permit "All" .htaccess overrides for this directory tree
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

(When you create an addon domain in cPanel, it should already do this for you.)

> is the sub/add-on-domain in the wrong place?

No, not necessarily. This depends on what you are doing exactly. If the addon domain is meant to be entirely separate from the main domain, then doing it this way is preferred.

> should it be under public_html for instance?

It should not matter. However, if you point the addon domain to a subdirectory off the main domain then the `.htaccess` in the document root of the main domain can affect the addon domain as well. To keep them separate you would need to move the main domain's content into another subdirectory and rewrite requests from the document root to this subdirectory (these are just workarounds for when you don't have access to the server config).

However, this should mean that `.htaccess` overrides will be enabled for the addon domain since they are enabled for the parent directory. So, unless something in the server config is explicitly preventing this, it will be enabled for all subdirectories as well.

Comment: No it doesn't work...

Comment: @ABRO I've updated my answer.

Comment: Hi Mr White. I moved the domain under public_html didn't work, changed the code what you advised originally, didn't work, I then created a new .htaccess file copied the code accross and it worked... looks like it was corrupted. Thanks for all the help, at least I learned somethings..

Comment: @ABRO "looks like it was corrupted." - Hhhmm, that's weird. A corrupt file should still have generated an "error". (Unless perhaps you are on a LiteSpeed server and not Apache?) Are you sure the file perms/ownership were correct?